# Can I allocate all available RAM?

Tags: c++, new-operator

I am trying to allocate all available RAM.  I was expecting my computer to start running poorly, but nothing bad happens with the following program in Visual Studio.

```
int main()
{
   while (true)
   {
        int* i = new int[1000];
   }

    return 0;
}
```

This program was not even infinite. It ended very quickly. Why? I was expecting to see the memory usage grow, and then who the hell knows what.

I have tried even this, and still no problem:

```
int main()
{
   while (true)
   {
        int* i = new int[1000];

        for (int k = 0; k < 1000; ++k)
            i[k] = k;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

It works a bit and says "Press Any Key...".  What the hell?

Comment: "I have tried this and nothing bad happened with Visual Studio. Why?" - Release build and optimized away? Your code doesn't actually use i. You're also not allocating "RAM"; Windows uses virtual memory.

Comment: Where does that virtual memory come from? RAM? And why this is optimized away? This is a bad code.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Of course RAM is the physical implementation of memory, but that doesn't mean that X bytes are actually allocated in RAM when you call malloc(X)

Comment: _"why this is optimized away?"_ Because it doesn't do anything? Programs do things. They take input and give output. Yours has _no_ observable semantics.

Comment: Rather than using `operator new`, you should be using an operating system call to get memory.  The operating system call should have more functionality than `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually you will use all your memory and swap file  - but you need to use a 64 bit compiler and 64 bit settings, 
Otherwise the new will fail eventually when you'll run out of the 2gb (or 4 ? can't remember) you can allocate.

Comment: Also should be mentioned that some implementations of `malloc` can be optimistic

Comment: you can adjust the program to overcome this optimization and actually set values to those allocation. the idea is what happen when you allocate all the memory....

Comment: You can use all of the memory allocated to your program, by using a 32-bit compiler and 32-bit settings.  It's called paging.  It's an ancient art that allows computers to use more memory than they can directly address.

Answer (score 1):

Of course if you allocated all of your computer's RAM, your computer would fail. Computers grinding to a halt aren't uncommon, if you're running leaking/bloated software e.g. Google Chrome. On Linux systems you can trigger the spontaneous murder of processes when available memory is exhausted.

And if you expected something like a fire, you'll have to use an operating system that doesn't do its job, and a CPU that … I dunno, has a really serious bug. I guess you'll probably want a criminally dangerous and market-banned PSU, too.

Anyway, in order to reach that point, you'll need to:

- Persuade your compiler to *actually* cause an allocation, by making your program *do something* with this memory — this must be sufficient work for the loop not to be entirely removed from your program;
- Blow through the quantity of disk space set aside for your pagefile.

You'll never get the program to run "infinitely". Nothing runs "infinitely".

Comment: A forever loop, such as `while(1)` or `for(;;;)` will run infinitely, from the program's perspective, as long as no crashes occur.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Such a loop (assuming a body that performs no I/O or one of a few other things) has undefined behaviour from the program's perspective. This means you can't make rationalisations like that. Regardless, I was referring to the OP's practical observation that _"this program was not even infinite"_.

Answer (score 1):

Just did the experiment on ubuntu 15.10 (64). The system ran normally just long enough for me to get "System Monitor" running.  (should have done that first, oops)

System monitor reported a few seconds growth of ram use, until all available ram filled (~3.9G), then (at about 15 sec) the system appeared to lock up ... the mouse indicator stopped tracking mouse movements, and keyboard input appeared to be ignored (but may have been queuing somewhere), even System Monitor updates seemed to stop.

I would guess the apparent 'lock up' was because the 4 GByte swap started filling and thrashing.

After a minute or 2, my impatience won out, and I forced a reboot.

---

I have seen this behaviour before, earlier this year.  I think it was a Firefox problem, but I have not been able to reproduce.

Comment: This is what I have expected. But I didn't get and was surprised and asked this question. But people think I was drunk :D

Comment: Should have mentioned - I used -O0 when allocating big blocks of dynamic memory.